# find the number of different 4-digit numbers that can be formed

Tags: combinatorics

Qns: Find the number of different $4$-digit numbers that can be formed from the digits $3$, $4$, $6$ and $8$ with no repeated digit. And if the numbers must be divisible by $4$.

Ans: $10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know, the number is divisible by $4$ if the number made from its last two digits is divisible by $4$.
So there are pairs of digits we can put in the end: $36, 48, 64, 68, 84$
 ($5$ variants).
As we have two remaining positions and two remaining digits, we can form $2$ variants of *first* two digits for each variant of *last* two digits. As a result:
$$ 5 \times 2 = 10 $$